# Update cell in jTable using SQL

Tags: java, sql, jtable

I want to know how I can update specific cells in jTable (in Java) using SQL.

This my try but it doesn't work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int sel_tab=jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    myDbConnection dbconnect;
    dbconnect = new myDbConnection();
        ResultSet resultSet =null;
        resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location, status1 FROM pledges ");     
   if(e.getSource()==jButton1){
        try {
        String n = resultSet.getString("id");
        String a = resultSet.getString("area");
        String p = resultSet.getString("location");
        String se = resultSet.getString("status1");
            dbconnect.excuteUpdate("update pledges SET area="+ a +" whare id= "+sel_tab+"");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {;}
   }
}
```

Note: I am working in Netbeans.

Comment: well, where are you updating the TableModel?

Comment: i,m updating my table from JDBC derpy database

Comment: while i,m searching in net i road about TableModelListener & fireTableCellUpdated ..i tried to do it but didn't work correctly..if some one could help me in this it will be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I've found the correct answer

the following code will explain every thing

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


   if(e.getSource()==jButton1){



               jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      myDbConnection dbconnect;
    dbconnect = new myDbConnection();
         ResultSet resultSet =null;
        resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location, status1 FROM pledges ");
       int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
    int viewRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow(); // view row with sort
    int modelRow = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow); // convert
    dbconnect.excuteUpdate("update pledges set area ='" + data + "' where id = '"+jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow,0) +"'"  );
      System.out.println("Table value changed "+data);
  }
});
```

thanks for every one helped me